# What is an idiomatic Scala way to "remove" one element from an immutable List?

Tags: list, scala

I have a List, which may contain elements that will compare as equal. I would like a similar List, but with one element removed. So from (A, B, C, B, D) I would like to be able to "remove" just one B to get e.g. (A, C, B, D). The order of the elements in the result does not matter.

I have working code, written in a Lisp-inspired way in Scala. Is there a more idiomatic way
to do this?

The context is a card game where two decks of standard cards are in play, so there may
be duplicate cards but still played one at a time.

```
def removeOne(c: Card, left: List[Card], right: List[Card]): List[Card] = {
  if (Nil == right) {
    return left
  }
  if (c == right.head) {
    return left ::: right.tail
  }
  return removeOne(c, right.head :: left, right.tail)
}

def removeCard(c: Card, cards: List[Card]): List[Card] = {
  return removeOne(c, Nil, cards)
}
```

Comment: Added a note that the order of the result List does not matter in this specific case.

Comment: so the `List[Card]` in this question is a player's hand?

Comment: @Ken Bloom, yes that's right a player's hand.

Comment: You know, I searched for a question like this for a while, then posted the same question, then found this one while I was browsing and waiting for people to answer mine.  Guess I should vote to close my own question now as a duplicate. ;-)

Comment: This question for Clojure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662447/what-is-idiomatic-clojure-to-remove-a-single-instance-from-many-in-a-list

Comment: Same question, discussed from the efficiency point of view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084212/is-scala-idiomatic-coding-style-just-a-cool-trap-for-writing-inefficient-code

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous to me.   In the the case where there are multiple elements on the list with the same value, which should be removed?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

I haven't seen this possibility in the answers above, so:

```
scala> def remove(num: Int, list: List[Int]) = list diff List(num)
remove: (num: Int,list: List[Int])List[Int]

scala> remove(2,List(1,2,3,4,5))
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 4, 5)
```

Edit:

```
scala> remove(2,List(2,2,2))
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 2)
```

Like a charm :-).

Comment: Nice! I would add another 2 to the list to make clear that only one element is removed.

Answer (score 43):

You could use the `filterNot` method.

```
val data = "test"
list = List("this", "is", "a", "test")
list.filterNot(elm => elm == data)
```

Comment: This will remove all elements that are equal to "test" - not what is asked for ;)

Comment: Actually it will do exactly what you need. It will return all elements from the list except those which aren't equal to "test". Pay attention  that it uses **filterNot**

Comment: The original question was how to remove a SINGLE instance. Not all instances.

Comment: @Søren Mathiasen  if i want to filter out multiple elements like sequence like val data = Seq("test","a") , how to do it ?

Answer (score 18):

You could try this:

```
scala> val (left,right) = List(1,2,3,2,4).span(_ != 2)
left: List[Int] = List(1)
right: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 2, 4)

scala> left ::: right.tail                            
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 2, 4)
```

And as method:

```
def removeInt(i: Int, li: List[Int]) = {
   val (left, right) = li.span(_ != i)
   left ::: right.drop(1)
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `left ::: right.drop(1)` is shorter than the if statement with `isEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks, is there any circumstance to prefer .drop(1) over .tail, or vice versa?

Comment: @James Petry - If you call `tail` on an empty list you get an exception: `scala> List().tail
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list`. `drop(1)` on an empty list however returns an empty list.

Comment: `tail` throws an exception if the list is empty (i.e. there is no `head`).  `drop(1)` on an empty list just yields another empty list.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, the collections hierarchy got itself into a bit of a mess with `-` on `List`.  For `ArrayBuffer` it works just like you might hope:

```
scala> collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,2,4) - 2
res0: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 3, 2, 4)
```

but, sadly, `List` ended up with a `filterNot`-style implementation and thus does the "wrong thing" *and* throws a deprecation warning at you (sensible enough, since it is actually `filterNot`ing):

```
scala> List(1,2,3,2,4) - 2                          
warning: there were deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 4)
```

So arguably the easiest thing to do is convert `List` into a collection that does this right, and then convert back again:

```
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer._
scala> ((ArrayBuffer() ++ List(1,2,3,2,4)) - 2).toList
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 2, 4)
```

Alternatively, you could keep the logic of the code you've got but make the style more idiomatic:

```
def removeInt(i: Int, li: List[Int]) = {
  def removeOne(i: Int, left: List[Int], right: List[Int]): List[Int] = right match {
    case r :: rest =>
      if (r == i) left.reverse ::: rest
      else removeOne(i, r :: left, rest)
    case Nil => left.reverse
  }
  removeOne(i, Nil, li)
}

scala> removeInt(2, List(1,2,3,2,4))
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 2, 4)
```

Comment: `removeInt(5,List(1,2,6,4,5,3,6,4,6,5,1))` yields `List(4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 6, 5, 1)`. I think this is not what you wanted.

Comment: @Ken Bloom - Indeed.  It's an error in the original algorithm, which I copied without thinking enough.  Fixed now.

Comment: More an omission in the question spec, as the order doesn't matter in my specific case. Good to see the order-preserving version though, thanks.

Comment: @Rex: what do you mean by 'filterNot does the "wrong thing"'? That it's removing all occurrences? And why does it throw a deprecation warning? Thanks

Comment: @teo - It removes all occurrences (which is not what is desired here), and it is deprecated because it is arguably broken (or perhaps the desired behavior is unclear--either way, it's deprecated in 2.9 and gone in 2.10).

Answer (score 5):

```
 def removeAtIdx[T](idx: Int, listToRemoveFrom: List[T]): List[T] = {
    assert(listToRemoveFrom.length > idx && idx >= 0)
    val (left, _ :: right) = listToRemoveFrom.splitAt(idx)
    left ++ right
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
def removeCard(c: Card, cards: List[Card]) = {
  val (head, tail) = cards span {c!=}   
  head ::: 
  (tail match {
    case x :: xs => xs
    case Nil => Nil
  })
}
```

If you see `return`, there's something wrong.

Comment: This doesn't do what he wants, which is to remove only the first instance of `c`

Comment: This will remove all cards `c`, but only first should be removed.

Comment: I should read the questions more carefully! corrected my answer.

Comment: +1 for "If you see return, there's something wrong."  That's a very important "idiomatic Scala" lesson by itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
// throws a MatchError exception if i isn't found in li
def remove[A](i:A, li:List[A]) = {
   val (head,_::tail) = li.span(i != _)
   head ::: tail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As one possible solutions you can find index of the first suitable element and then remove element at this index:

```
def removeOne(l: List[Card], c: Card) = l indexOf c match {
    case -1 => l
    case n => (l take n) ++ (l drop (n + 1))
}
```

Comment: See my answer using `span` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just another thought on how to do this using a fold:

```
def remove[A](item : A, lst : List[A]) : List[A] = {
    lst.:\[List[A]](Nil)((lst, lstItem) => 
       if (lstItem == item) lst else lstItem::lst )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic Tail Recursion Solution:

```
def removeElement[T](list: List[T], ele: T): List[T] = {
    @tailrec
    def removeElementHelper(list: List[T],
                            accumList: List[T] = List[T]()): List[T] = {
      if (list.length == 1) {
        if (list.head == ele) accumList.reverse
        else accumList.reverse ::: list
      } else {
        list match {
          case head :: tail if (head != ele) =>
            removeElementHelper(tail, head :: accumList)
          case head :: tail if (head == ele) => (accumList.reverse ::: tail)
          case _                             => accumList
        }
      }
    }
    removeElementHelper(list)
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
val list : Array[Int] = Array(6, 5, 3, 1, 8, 7, 2)
val test2 = list.splitAt(list.length / 2)._2
val res = test2.patch(1, Nil, 1)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
object HelloWorld {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        var months: List[String] = List("December","November","October","September","August", "July","June","May","April","March","February","January")

        println("Deleting the reverse list one by one")

        var i = 0

        while (i < (months.length)){

            println("Deleting "+months.apply(i))

            months = (months.drop(1))

        }

        println(months)

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation (comments, description) as to how this answers the question?

Comment: 1. This question was asked, and answered, 5 years ago. 2. The OP asked for "idiomatic" Scala.  Using 2 `var`s and a `while` loop is not idiomatic Scala.