# Is Scala idiomatic coding style just a cool trap for writing inefficient code?

Tags: scala, performance

I sense that the Scala community has a little big obsession with writing "concise", "cool", **"scala idiomatic"**, "one-liner" -if possible- code. This is immediately followed by a comparison to Java/imperative/ugly code.

While this (sometimes) leads to easy to understand code, it also leads to inefficient code for 99% of developers. And this is where Java/C++ is not easy to beat.

Consider this simple problem: **Given a list of integers, remove the greatest element.** Ordering does not need to be preserved.

Here is my version of the solution (It may not be the greatest, but it's what the average non-rockstar developer would do).

```
def removeMaxCool(xs: List[Int]) = {
  val maxIndex = xs.indexOf(xs.max);
  xs.take(maxIndex) ::: xs.drop(maxIndex+1)
}
```

It's Scala idiomatic, concise, and uses a few nice list functions. It's also very inefficient. It traverses the list at least 3 or 4 times.

Here is my totally uncool, Java-like solution. It's also what a reasonable Java developer (or Scala novice) would write.

```
def removeMaxFast(xs: List[Int]) = {
    var res = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    var max = xs.head
    var first = true;   
    for (x <- xs) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            if (x > max) {
                res.append(max)
                max = x
            } else {
                res.append(x)
            }
        }
    }
    res.toList
}
```

Totally non-Scala idiomatic, non-functional, non-concise, but it's very efficient. It traverses the list only once!

So, if 99% of Java developers write more efficient code than 99% of Scala developers, this is a huge 
obstacle to cross for greater Scala adoption. Is there a way out of this trap?

I am looking for practical advice to avoid such "inefficiency traps" while keeping implementation clear ans concise.

**Clarification:** This question comes from a real-life scenario: I had to write a complex algorithm. First I wrote it in Scala, then I "had to" rewrite it in Java. The Java implementation was twice as long, and not that clear, but at the same time it was twice as fast. Rewriting the Scala code to be efficient would probably take some time and a somewhat deeper understanding of scala internal efficiencies (for vs. map vs. fold, etc)

Comment: I've voted to close (moving to programmers), but I'll note that a _really_ cool way of implementing this would be as a fold, which should be just as efficient as the Java version, and no more opaque

Comment: I would reopen this, since it is closely related to Scala coding style - and practical advice on efficiency.

Comment: The problem is not that concise, cool, idiomatic Scala code is inherently slow: the problem is simply that you cannot come up with a fast, elegant, concise, cool and idiomatic solution, which do *exists*! I'm pretty sure people with strong functional-programming background can easily find a fold, accumulating on a list and a partial maximum, pretty much like your Java-like code, that will traverse the list only once (and perform almost as well as your imperative code) and produce the expected result.

If you cannot find a solution, don't blame the language; you can only blame yourself.

Comment: As I added in the question, this is just an example. The collection can be large, or this can be called in an inner loop. My point was that the average Java developer would write faster code than the average Scala developer. And here are many of them. Maybe I am asking for too much, but is there an "efficient coding style guideline for Scala" somewhere? Maybe here in SO?

Comment: @Adrian: I disagree. An average **Scala developer**, that is, someone with average skill and **the correct mindset**, would come up with a fold. The *average Scala developer* you are talking about is someone who began with C/C++/Java/C#/etc (and is still an average programmer in those environments) and then started coding in Scala, but has not switched his mindset. This developer, obviously, would produce not-so-idiomatic and not-so-fast code.

Comment: If by "efficiency" you mean optimal performance, you should use Assembler. The code might not be as short and "cool" as Java, but Java can't beat Assembler's "efficiency".

Comment: As Daniel pointed out, the imperative code isn't efficient. But even if it were, so what? You write your application quickly (by using Scala), then use a profiler to find hotspots and the you can rewrite them

Comment: A good programmer would be using a Heap rather than a List in the first place, irrespectively of the language.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Let's discuss a fallacy in the question:

> So, if 99% of Java developers write more efficient code than 99% of
>   Scala developers, this is a huge obstacle to cross for greater Scala
>   adoption. Is there a way out of this trap?

This is presumed, with absolutely no evidence backing it up. If false, the question is moot.

Is there evidence to the contrary? Well, let's consider the question itself -- it doesn't prove anything, but shows things are not that clear.

> Totally non-Scala idiomatic, non-functional, non-concise, but it's
>   very efficient. It traverses the list only once!

Of the four claims in the first sentence, the first three are true, and the fourth, as shown by [user unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312172/user-unknown), is false! And why it is false? Because, contrary to what the second sentence states, it traverses the list more than once.

The code calls the following methods on it:

```
res.append(max)
res.append(x)
```

and

```
res.toList
```

Let's consider first `append`.

1. `append` takes a vararg parameter. That means `max` and `x` are first encapsulated into a sequence of some type (a `WrappedArray`, in fact), and then passed as parameter. A better method would have been `+=`.
2. Ok, `append` calls `++=`, which delegates to `+=`. But, first, it calls `ensureSize`, which is the second mistake (`+=` calls that too -- `++=` just optimizes that for multiple elements). Because an `Array` is a fixed size collection, which means that, at each resize, the whole `Array` must be copied!

So let's consider this. When you resize, Java first clears the memory by storing 0 in each element, then Scala copies each element of the previous array over to the new array. Since size doubles each time, this happens log(n) times, with the number of elements being copied increasing each time it happens.

Take for example n = 16. It does this four times, copying 1, 2, 4 and 8 elements respectively. Since Java has to clear each of these arrays, and each element must be read *and* written, each element copied represents 4 traversals of an element. Adding all we have (n - 1) * 4, or, roughly, 4 traversals of the complete list. If you count read and write as a single pass, as people often erroneously do, then it's still three traversals.

One can improve on this by initializing the `ArrayBuffer` with an initial size equal to the list that will be read, minus one, since we'll be discarding one element. To get this size, we need to traverse the list once, though.

Now let's consider `toList`. To put it simply, it traverses the whole list to create a new list.

So, we have 1 traversal for the algorithm, 3 or 4 traversals for resize, and 1 additional traversal for `toList`. That's 4 or 5 traversals.

The original algorithm is a bit difficult to analyse, because `take`, `drop` and `:::` traverse a variable number of elements. Adding all together, however, it does the equivalent of 3 traversals. If `splitAt` was used, it would be reduced to 2 traversals. With 2 more traversals to get the maximum, we get 5 traversals -- the same number as the non-functional, non-concise algorithm!

So, let's consider improvements.

On the imperative algorithm, if one uses `ListBuffer` and `+=`, then all methods are constant-time, which reduces it to a single traversal.

On the functional algorithm, it could be rewritten as:

```
val max = xs.max
val (before, _ :: after) = xs span (max !=)
before ::: after
```

That reduces it to a worst case of three traversals. Of course, there are other alternatives presented, based on recursion or fold, that solve it in one traversal.

And, most interesting of all, all of these algorithms are `O(n)`, and the only one which almost incurred (accidentally) in worst complexity was the imperative one (because of array copying). On the other hand, the *cache* characteristics of the imperative one might well make it faster, because the data is contiguous in memory. That, however, is unrelated to either big-Oh or functional vs imperative, and it is just a matter of the data structures that were chosen.

So, if we actually go to the trouble of benchmarking, analyzing the results, considering performance of methods, and looking into ways of optimizing it, then we can find faster ways to do this in an imperative manner than in a functional manner.

But all this effort is very different from saying the average Java programmer code will be faster than the average Scala programmer code -- if the question is an example, that is simply false. And even discounting the question, we have seen no evidence that the fundamental premise of the question is true.

**EDIT**

First, let me restate my point, because it seems I wasn't clear. My point is that the code the average Java programmer writes may seem to be more efficient, but actually isn't. Or, put another way, traditional Java style doesn't gain you performance -- only hard work does, be it Java or Scala.

Next, I have a benchmark and results too, including almost all solutions suggested. Two interesting points about it:

1. Depending on list size, the creation of objects can have a bigger impact than multiple traversals of the list. The original functional code by Adrian takes advantage of the fact that lists are persistent data structures by *not copying* the elements right of the maximum element at all. If a `Vector` was used instead, both left and right sides would be mostly unchanged, which might lead to even better performance.
2. Even though user unknown and paradigmatic have similar recursive solutions, paradigmatic's is way faster. The reason for that is that he avoids pattern matching. Pattern matching can be really slow.

The benchmark code is [here](https://gist.github.com/1152616), and the results are [here](https://gist.github.com/1152764).

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the answer. Very helpful. But don't get me wrong: I like Scala very much. Here I am trying to have a constructive criticism and raise an issue that comes from the pragmatic Java crowd and is not insignificant. Scala in inexperienced hands can produce relatively inefficient code, because of the "lure" of scala idiomatic style. As @Kipton Barros said in his answer, the proof is in the Scala library code which many times is not in functional style, not easily readable, i.e. not Scala idiomatic. It may have been the same in the C to C++ transition, as you said.

Comment: Again, I did not claim that the sample code in the questions is the best that I (or most of us here) can do. It was just as an example of code that IS written.   Related to the array copying, the array is by default initialized at 8 elements, so there is no copy at n =  1, 2, 4.

Comment: @Adrian Current code initializes it with 16, but from there on the same thing applies. I'm ignoring that just to show how the complexity of that copy in the general case (ie, everything above 16). But you seem to have missed my point: my point is that the code the average Java programmer writes may _seem_ to be more efficient, but actually isn't. Or, put another way, traditional Java style doesn't gain you performance -- only hard work does, be it Java or Scala.

Comment: Daniel and his amazing answers. Thanks again @Daniel

Comment: In my experience, the keys to high performance are: (1) picking an algorithm with good complexity, and (2) avoiding GC and boxing. For performance critical code, such as number crunching and scientific computing, I use Arrays with packed primitive values and iterate with while or (sometimes) for loops. This is necessarily an imperative style, and I'm glad Scala doesn't penalize it.

Comment: @Kipton Nowadays is very important to take into consideration the memory. Cache memory is way faster, so you want good locality and avoid anything that might invalidate the cache. Also, automatic memory management has a cost of its own, so anything you do to decrease garbage collection will also impact on performance. That's why Malvolio is right: performance optimization must be benchmark/profiler driven.

Comment: Thank you for posting the benchmarks. Seeing actual numbers is very enlightening.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I'm relatively new to Scala but experienced programmer in Java. When I discovered and started to learn Scala I learnt that obtaining the maximum of Scala requires a great effort. I'm sure that with years of experience Scala will beat Java because better idiom. But if you take one programmer with 2 years Java, 2 years of Scala he will do better at Java. Mainly because that's how we learnt on school! Scala requires a new way of thinking. I'm sure that when you got it you will never leave it...

Answer (score 26):

```
def removeOneMax (xs: List [Int]) : List [Int] = xs match {                                  
    case x :: Nil => Nil 
    case a :: b :: xs => if (a < b) a :: removeOneMax (b :: xs) else b :: removeOneMax (a :: xs) 
    case Nil => Nil 
}
```

Here is a recursive method, which only iterates once. If you need performance, you have to think about it, if not, not.

You can make it tail-recursive in the standard way: giving an extra parameter `carry`, which is per default the empty List, and collects the result while iterating. That is, of course, a bit longer, but if you need performance, you have to pay for it:

```
import annotation.tailrec 
@tailrec
def removeOneMax (xs: List [Int], carry: List [Int] = List.empty) : List [Int] = xs match {                                  
  case a :: b :: xs => if (a < b) removeOneMax (b :: xs, a :: carry) else removeOneMax (a :: xs, b :: carry) 
  case x :: Nil => carry 
  case Nil => Nil 
}
```

I don't know what the chances are, that later compilers will improve slower map-calls to be as fast as while-loops. However: You rarely need high speed solutions, but if you need them often, you will learn them fast.

Do you know how big your collection has to be, to use a whole second for your solution on your machine?

As oneliner, similar to Daniel C. Sobrals solution:

```
((Nil : List[Int], xs(0)) /: xs.tail) ((p, x)=> if (p._2 > x) (x :: p._1, p._2) else ((p._2 :: p._1), x))._1
```

but that is hard to read, and I didn't measure the effective performance. The normal pattern is (x /: xs) ((a, b) => /* something */). Here, x and a are pairs of List-so-far and max-so-far, which solves the problem to bring everything into one line of code, but isn't very readable. However, you can earn reputation on CodeGolf this way, and maybe someone likes to make a performance measurement.

#### And now to our big surprise, some measurements:

An updated timing-method, to get the garbage collection out of the way, and have the hotspot-compiler warm up, a main, and many methods from this thread, together in an Object named

```
object PerfRemMax {

  def timed (name: String, xs: List [Int]) (f: List [Int] => List [Int]) = {
    val a = System.currentTimeMillis 
    val res = f (xs)
    val z = System.currentTimeMillis 
    val delta = z-a
    println (name + ": "  + (delta / 1000.0))
    res
  }

def main (args: Array [String]) : Unit = {
  val n = args(0).toInt
  val funs : List [(String, List[Int] => List[Int])] = List (
    "indexOf/take-drop" -> adrian1 _, 
    "arraybuf"      -> adrian2 _, /* out of memory */
    "paradigmatic1"     -> pm1 _, /**/
    "paradigmatic2"     -> pm2 _, 
    // "match" -> uu1 _, /*oom*/
    "tailrec match"     -> uu2 _, 
    "foldLeft"      -> uu3 _,
    "buf-=buf.max"  -> soc1 _, 
    "for/yield"     -> soc2 _,
    "splitAt"       -> daniel1,
    "ListBuffer"    -> daniel2
    )

  val r = util.Random 
  val xs = (for (x <- 1 to n) yield r.nextInt (n)).toList 

// With 1 Mio. as param, it starts with 100 000, 200k, 300k, ... 1Mio. cases. 
// a) warmup
// b) look, where the process gets linear to size  
  funs.foreach (f => {
    (1 to 10) foreach (i => {
        timed (f._1, xs.take (n/10 * i)) (f._2)
        compat.Platform.collectGarbage
    });
    println ()
  })
}
```

I renamed all the methods, and had to modify uu2 a bit, to fit to the common method declaration (List [Int] => List [Int]).

From the long result, i only provide the output for 1M invocations:

```
scala -Dserver PerfRemMax 2000000
indexOf/take-drop:  0.882
arraybuf:   1.681
paradigmatic1:  0.55
paradigmatic2:  1.13
tailrec match: 0.812
foldLeft:   1.054
buf-=buf.max:   1.185
for/yield:  0.725
splitAt:    1.127
ListBuffer: 0.61
```

The numbers aren't completly stable, depending on the sample size, and a bit varying from run to run. For example, for 100k to 1M runs, in steps of 100k, the timing for splitAt was as follows:

```
splitAt: 0.109
splitAt: 0.118
splitAt: 0.129
splitAt: 0.139
splitAt: 0.157
splitAt: 0.166
splitAt: 0.749
splitAt: 0.752
splitAt: 1.444
splitAt: 1.127
```

The initial solution is already pretty fast. `splitAt` is a modification from Daniel, often faster, but not always.

The measurement was done on a single core 2Ghz Centrino, running xUbuntu Linux, Scala-2.8 with Sun-Java-1.6 (desktop).

The two lessons for me are:

- always measure your performance improvements; it is very hard to estimate it, if you don't do it on a daily basis
- it is not only fun, to write functional code - sometimes the result is even faster

[Here is a link to my benchmarkcode, if somebody is interested.](https://gist.github.com/1152783/d8443dea977a1e23519592c98d12d594ea08f186)

Comment: The only drawback is that it is not tail-recursive. (I assume the OP's list must be huge, otherwise this question is meaningless, just another example of premature optimization)

Comment: Yes. Of course, you loose a bit of the briefness, with annotation, import and a carry-parameter. I updated my answer, to include the tailrec-way.

Comment: The result is not stable because you didn't write your microbenchmark correctly. You should run the functions many times so that they are JIT-compiled, before timing them. Moreover, make sure you activate Scala's optimizer. Without optimizations, Scala for loops can be slower than Scala while loops: `for (x <- xs) {stuff}` is translated to `xs foreach stuff`, where `stuff` is a closure invoked at every iteration.

Comment: I'm sure I'm boring everyone on SO with this but I want everybody to notice: **the OP's example of a lazy, inefficient implementation was NEVER as slow as all the improvements that anyone suggested**.  Part of that is certainly measurement error (as @Blaisorblade points out) but part of it is that optimization is very difficult, very unintuitive, and if not benchmark-driven, rarely worth doing.

Comment: @Blaisorblade: Yes. How many warm ups do you suggest? But not every code is run on the server, where, over time, the code is JIT-compiled.

Comment: No, that's an interesting comment. And here's why performance here is not intuitive. First, the complexity of all algorithms is the same, so we are talking about constant factors, and comparing the constant factors involved in 3-4 traversals with constant factors for e.g. object creation (for the tuples, in the uu3 solution, and for building many more new cons cells, in the uu2 solution). Looking at it this way, guessing which is bigger is clearly way error-prone.

Comment: @user unknown: see http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.microBenchmark, especially pitfall #5. Your objection to warmup is interesting - but you care about performance for bottlenecks, and most of them should be JIT-compiled, actually after ~1000 iterations of the same code (you can check what happens via suitable options, see the link). Performance bottlenecks in shortly running Java programs are a huge problem. The usual workaround is to keep the program in memory as a server, and submit a task when you need to run one, exactly like FSC; JIT compilation is one of the motivations.

Comment: @user Even on JVM in client mode things can be JITed if run enough times. If they are not run enough times, then the code is unlikely to be in a hot spot.

Comment: @user On a side note, could you provide results for adrian1 using `splitAt` instead of `drop` and `take`, and adrian2 using `ListBuffer` instead of `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: @Malvolio Not so. Half the answers suggest a fold, which beat the original algorithm before JIT kicked in for that. But it is a very interesting point, as the allegations of the question that I took at face value are, in fact, false. I'll make a separate answer on that alone.

Comment: @Daniel: Well, maybe we can take this conversation to chat, somehow? I know how to open a chatroom, so I will do it right now - here is the link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2579/scala-performance

Comment: @Blaisorblade: That page talks about 10.000 for warming up - I had 3 runs of 100 000, so the first could count as warmup. You're too invited to chat (as everybody else, who is interested in the topic).

Comment: splitAt() times are proportional to the distance of max from the front of the list.

Comment: Similarly, the time for take/drop will vary with the position of max.

Answer (score 23):

First of all, the behavior of the methods you presented is not the same. The first one keeps the element ordering, while the second one doesn't.

Second, among all the possible solution which could be qualified as "idiomatic", some are more efficient than others. Staying very close to your example, you can for instance use tail-recursion to eliminate variables and manual state management:

```
def removeMax1( xs: List[Int] ) = {
  def rec( max: Int, rest: List[Int], result: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if( rest.isEmpty ) result
    else if( rest.head > max ) rec( rest.head, rest.tail, max :: result)
    else rec( max, rest.tail, rest.head :: result )
  }
  rec( xs.head, xs.tail, List() )
}
```

or fold the list:

```
def removeMax2( xs: List[Int] ) = {
  val result = xs.tail.foldLeft( xs.head -> List[Int]() ) { 
    (acc,x) =>
      val (max,res) = acc
      if( x > max ) x -> ( max :: res )
      else max -> ( x :: res )
  }
  result._2
}
```

If you want to keep the original insertion order, you can (at the expense of having two passes, rather than one) without any effort write something like:

```
def removeMax3( xs: List[Int] ) = {
  val max = xs.max
  xs.filterNot( _ == max )
}
```

which is more clear than your first example.

Comment: Solution 3 removes ALL elements which are == MAX, while removeMaxCool only removed one element, matching MAX.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Since the real intent was not precised, I'll let the example as it is.

Comment: Sadly, this answer is undervoted, given it presents the second fastest solution of all (the fastest one being the one presented as being "slow" in the question).

Answer (score 18):

The biggest inefficiency when you're writing a program is worrying about the wrong things. This is usually the wrong thing to worry about. Why?

1. Developer time is generally much more expensive than CPU time — in fact, there is usually a dearth of the former and a surplus of the latter.
2. Most code does not need to be very efficient because it will never be running on million-item datasets multiple times every second.
3. Most code does need to bug free, and less code is less room for bugs to hide.

Comment: Well, yes, but after writing scala code for some thousand hours, we are allowed to do silly, little microbenchmarks, just for entertainment, and to convince ourselves again, that we rarely need so much performance, and that everything, what we estimate and don't measure, is wrong. :) And having a discussion about it, can help us learn what to look for. And sometimes you can save your users just a second, but if you have a 32 million users, that is more than a year.

Answer (score 10):

The example you gave is not very functional, actually. Here's what you are doing:

```
// Given a list of Int
def removeMaxCool(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {

  // Find the index of the biggest Int
  val maxIndex = xs.indexOf(xs.max);

  // Then take the ints before and after it, and then concatenate then
  xs.take(maxIndex) ::: xs.drop(maxIndex+1)
}
```

Mind you, it is not *bad*, but you know when functional code is at its best when it describes what you want, instead of how you want it. As a minor criticism, if you used `splitAt` instead of `take` and `drop` you could improve it slightly.

Another way of doing it is this:

```
def removeMaxCool(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  // the result is the folding of the tail over the head 
  // and an empty list
  xs.tail.foldLeft(xs.head -> List[Int]()) {

    // Where the accumulated list is increased by the
    // lesser of the current element and the accumulated
    // element, and the accumulated element is the maximum between them
    case ((max, ys), x) => 
      if (x > max) (x, max :: ys)
      else (max, x :: ys)

  // and of which we return only the accumulated list
  }._2
}
```

Now, let's discuss the main issue. Is this code slower than the Java one? Most certainly! Is the Java code slower than a C equivalent? You can bet it is, JIT or no JIT. And if you write it directly in assembler, you can make it even faster!

But the cost of that speed is that you get more bugs, you spend more time trying to understand the code to debug it, and you have less visibility of what the overall program is doing as opposed to what a little piece of code is doing -- which might result in performance problems of its own.

So my answer is simple: if you think the speed penalty of programming in Scala is not worth the gains it brings, you should program in assembler. If you think I'm being radical, then I counter that you just chose the familiar as being the "ideal" trade off.

Do I think performance doesn't matter? Not at all! I think one of the main advantages of Scala is leveraging gains often found in dynamically typed languages with the performance of a statically typed language! Performance matters, algorithm complexity matters a lot, and constant costs matters too.

But, whenever there is a *choice* between performance and readability and maintainability, the latter is preferable. Sure, if performance *must* be improved, then there isn't a choice: you have to sacrifice something to it. And if there's no lost in readability/maintainability -- such as Scala vs dynamically typed languages -- sure, go for performance.

Lastly, to gain performance out of functional programming you have to know functional algorithms and data structures. Sure, 99% of Java programmers with 5-10 years experience will beat the performance of 99% of Scala programmers with 6 months experience. The same was true for imperative programming vs object oriented programming a couple of decades ago, and history shows it didn't matter.

**EDIT**

As a side note, your "fast" algorithm suffer from a serious problem: you use `ArrayBuffer`. That collection does not have constant time append, and has linear time `toList`. If you use `ListBuffer` instead, you get constant time append *and* `toList`.

Comment: You surely aren't claiming that your code here is better at "describing what you want, instead of how you want it" -are you???

Answer (score 8):

For reference, here's how `splitAt` is defined in [TraversableLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableLike) in the Scala standard library,

```
def splitAt(n: Int): (Repr, Repr) = {
  val l, r = newBuilder
  l.sizeHintBounded(n, this)
  if (n >= 0) r.sizeHint(this, -n)
  var i = 0
  for (x <- this) {
    (if (i < n) l else r) += x
    i += 1
  }
  (l.result, r.result)
}
```

It's not unlike your example code of what a Java programmer might come up with.

I like Scala because, where performance matters, mutability is a reasonable way to go. The collections library is a great example; especially how it hides this mutability behind a functional interface.

Where performance isn't as important, such as some application code, the higher order functions in Scala's library allow great expressivity and programmer efficiency.

---

Out of curiosity, I picked an arbitrary large file in the Scala compiler ([scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala)) and counted something like 37 for loops, 11 while loops, 6 concatenations (`++`), and 1 fold (it happens to be a `foldRight`).

Comment: This is a great response, and example. The essence is: if you really need efficiency, don't worry about being "scala-cool".

Comment: If you choose to write an implementation tuned for efficiency, it's a good idea to still write a more obviously correct (if slower) version, and use that to test the fast one. Scalacheck is a great tool for this.

Comment: Also, 27 var's in scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers.scala

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
def removeMax(xs: List[Int]) = {
  val buf = xs.toBuffer
  buf -= (buf.max)
}
```

A bit more ugly, but faster:

```
def removeMax(xs: List[Int]) = {
  var max = xs.head
  for ( x <- xs.tail ) 
  yield {
    if (x > max) { val result = max; max = x; result}
    else x
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(myList.foldLeft((List[Int](), None: Option[Int]))) {
  case ((_, None),     x) => (List(),               Some(x))
  case ((Nil, Some(m), x) => (List(Math.min(x, m)), Some(Math.max(x, m))
  case ((l, Some(m),   x) => (Math.min(x, m) :: l,  Some(Math.max(x, m))
})._1
```

Idiomatic, functional, traverses only once. Maybe somewhat cryptic if you are not used to functional-programming idioms.

Let's try to explain what is happening here. I will try to make it as simple as possible, lacking some rigor.

A **fold** is an operation on a `List[A]` (that is, a list that contains elements of type `A`) that will take an initial state `s0: S` (that is, an instance of a type `S`) and a function `f: (S, A) => S` (that is, a function that takes the current state and an element from the list, and gives the next state, ie, it updates the state according to the next element).

The operation will then iterate over the elements of the list, using each one to update the state according to the given function. In Java, it would be something like:

```
interface Function<T, R> { R apply(T t); }
class Pair<A, B> { ... }
<State> State fold(List<A> list, State s0, Function<Pair<A, State>, State> f) {
  State s = s0;
  for (A a: list) {
    s = f.apply(new Pair<A, State>(a, s));
  }
  return s;
}
```

For example, if you want to add all the elements of a `List[Int]`, the state would be the partial sum, that would have to be initialized to 0, and the new state produced by a function would simply add the current state to the current element being processed:

```
myList.fold(0)((partialSum, element) => partialSum + element)
```

Try to write a fold to multiply the elements of a list, then another one to find extreme values (max, min).

Now, the fold presented above is a bit more complex, since the state is composed of the new list being created along with the maximum element found so far. The function that updates the state is more or less straightforward once you grasp these concepts. It simply puts into the new list the minimum between the current maximum and the current element, while the other value goes to the current maximum of the updated state.

What is a bit more complex than to understand this (if you have no FP background) is to come up with this solution. However, this is only to show you that it exists, can be done. It's just a completely different mindset.

EDIT: As you see, the first and second `case` in the solution I proposed are used to *setup* the fold. It is equivalent to what you see in other answers when they do `xs.tail.fold((xs.head, ...)) {...}`. Note that the solutions proposed until now using `xs.tail/xs.head` don't cover the case in which `xs` is `List()`, and will throw an exception. The solution above will return `List()` instead. Since you didn't specify the behavior of the function on empty lists, both are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be:

```
package code.array

object SliceArrays {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(removeMaxCool(Vector(1,2,3,100,12,23,44)))
  }
  def removeMaxCool(xs: Vector[Int]) = xs.filter(_ < xs.max)
}
```

Using Vector instead of List, the reason is that Vector is more versatile and has a better general performance and time complexity if compared to List.

Consider the following collections operations: 
 **head, tail,  apply, update, prepend, append**

Vector takes an amortized constant time for all operations, as per Scala docs:
"The operation takes effectively constant time, but this might depend on some assumptions such as maximum length of a vector or distribution of hash keys"

While List takes constant time only for head, tail and prepend operations.

Using

> scalac -print

generates:

```
package code.array {
  object SliceArrays extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = scala.Predef.println(SliceArrays.this.removeMaxCool(scala.`package`.Vector().apply(scala.Predef.wrapIntArray(Array[Int]{1, 2, 3, 100, 12, 23, 44})).$asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Vector]()));
    def removeMaxCool(xs: scala.collection.immutable.Vector): scala.collection.immutable.Vector = xs.filter({
  ((x$1: Int) => SliceArrays.this.$anonfun$removeMaxCool$1(xs, x$1))
}).$asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Vector]();
    final <artifact> private[this] def $anonfun$removeMaxCool$1(xs$1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector, x$1: Int): Boolean = x$1.<(scala.Int.unbox(xs$1.max(scala.math.Ordering$Int)));
    def <init>(): code.array.SliceArrays.type = {
      SliceArrays.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another contender.  This uses a ListBuffer, like Daniel's second offering, but shares the post-max tail of the original list, avoiding copying it.

```
  def shareTail(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    var res = ListBuffer[Int]()
    var maxTail = xs
    var first = true;
    var x = xs
    while ( x != Nil ) {
      if (x.head > maxTail.head) {
          while (!(maxTail.head == x.head)) {
              res += maxTail.head
              maxTail = maxTail.tail
          }
      }
      x = x.tail
    }
    res.prependToList(maxTail.tail)
  }
```