# Managing unused `List`s in Scala

Tags: scala, garbage-collection

Scala have wealth of immutable structure.

I wondered how do Scala manage excessive allocation and deallocation of such objects. How does it look for existing sublists when, e.g. concatenating `1` to `List(1,2,3)`. How does it track a certain `List` is not used, and allow the garbage collector to release it?

I would design it roughly like this

```
class List {
    private Map<Integer,WeakRef<List>> listCache;
    public List(Integer head,List tail) {...}
    public synchronized List prepend(Integer i) {
        if (listCache.get(i) != null) {
            if (listCache.get(i).get() == null) {
                listCache.put(i,new List(i,this));
            }
    }
}
```

How does Scala design that? Does it handle excessive allocations and deallocations well? What does it do about threading?

Comment: Your premise (equal immutable objects are the same object) may be faulty. While sharing is certainly very useful when the opportunity arises, enforcing it for all objects (you found a few) has too many problems to be generally viable.

Comment: His premise *is* faulty.

Comment: @delnan, removed wrong presumption. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala doesn't manage the deallocation of these objects at all. They are created on the heap as normal JVM objects, and garbage collected by the JVM just like any other Java or Scala object. As the comments on your question point out, it doesn't re-use lists created from previous calls to List() - it is always a new object.

To clarify the situation with concatenating lists - in this case, the resulting List object *does* hold a reference to the two ends of the list, but it still isn't doing any special caching of previously used lists or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, but in the specific example he gives Scala *does* reuse the List.

Comment: Indeed, concatenation is implemented using a reference to the original list(s). My understanding of the question was whether a subsequent, unrelated call to List(1,2,3) would somehow know to return the same reference as the original list. I'll update my question to be explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Let's write a simple `List` class:

```
sealed abstract class MyList[+T] {
  def head: T
  def tail: MyList[T]
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def prepend[T1 >: T](el: T1): MyList[T1]
}

object EmptyList extends MyList[Nothing] {
  def head: Nothing = throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("head of an empty list")
  def tail: MyList[Nothing] = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported operation exception")
  def isEmpty = true
  def prepend[T1 >: Nothing](el: T1): MyList[T1] = new Cons(el, this)

  override def toString = "EmptyList"
}

final class Cons[+T](val head: T, val tail: MyList[T]) extends MyList[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def prepend[T1 >: T](el: T1): MyList[T1] = new Cons(el, this)

  override def toString = head + ", " + tail.toString
}
```

Lists in Scala work like that. Consider, then, the example you mentioned:

```
scala> val list = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(3, EmptyList)))
list: Cons[Int] = 1, 2, 3, EmptyList

scala> val newList = list.prepend(1)
newList: MyList[Int] = 1, 1, 2, 3, EmptyList
```

So, questions:

- Did we look up lists for reuse? No.
- Did we reuse anything? Yes, we reused the list on which `prepend` was called.
- How will it be garbage collected? Just like any object in the JVM: when nothing points to it, it will be collected.

Of course, if I create another list like this:

```
val list2 = list.prepend(1)
```

Then `newList` and `list2` will share `list` but will be different lists even though they contain the same elements.

You might question (as was done in the comments) if this re-usability pattern is practical, or whether it brings any gains in real life, and the answer to that is that a *lot* of algorithms take advantage of it.

In fact, let me point out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7084212/53013), in which the allegedly "slow" code was actually faster than the allegedly "fast" code as well as the alternatives suggested in the answers. The *reason* why the "slow" code was nothing of the sort is this very pattern of reuse.

Comment: Um, the usage is a little artificial. You could do `val list = new Cons(1,knownlist);val list2 = new Cons(1,knownlist);` and reuse nothing. I understand that that's how scala list work, but it doesn't really help reuse for many reasonable usage patterns.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich Mmm? Both `list` and `list2` reuse `knownlist`. They are not _the same_ `List`, but most algorithms based on `List` take advantage of precisely this pattern, so this is hardly an artificial usage. In fact, this kind of reuse is precisely why the "slow" code beat all alternatives in [this famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7084212/53013).

Comment: both `list` and `list2` reuse `knownlist`, but `list3` and `list4` (which will use `list` and `list2`), will not reuse the same list. Trust me that in my use cases this will explode in your face if you wouldn't worry about it. Thanks for the link BTW, sounds interesting, I'll have a look.