# What is idiomatic Clojure to "remove" a single instance from many in a list?

Tags: list, clojure

I have a list, which may contain elements that will compare as equal. I would like a similar list, but with one element removed. So from (:a  :b  :c  :b  :d) I would like to be able to "remove" just *one* :b to get (:a :c :b :d).

The context is a hand in a card game where two decks of standard cards are in play, so there may be duplicate cards but still played one at a time.

I have working code, see below. Are there more idiomatic ways to do this in Clojure?

```
(defn remove-one [c left right]
  (if (= right ())
    left
    (if (= c (first right))
      (concat (reverse left) (rest right))
      (remove-one c (cons (first right) left) (rest right)))))

(defn remove-card [c cards]
  (remove-one c () cards))
```

Here are the Scala answers I got a while ago: [What is an idiomatic Scala way to "remove" one element from an immutable List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636717/what-is-an-idiomatic-scala-way-to-remove-one-element-from-an-immutable-list)

Comment: As a footnote, I looked into the source code of the preferred answer to my Scala version of this question. It turns out the diff function in Scala uses a mutable hash to count the number of occurrences to remove from a multi-set.

Comment: Just for clarification : does it matter which :b counts as a duplicate here ? From the example output , you 'dropped' the first :b, but would it still be equivalent to have dropped the second :b instead ? [abcbd -> acdb, but would abcd also be acceptable?]

Comment: @monojohnny, abcd is just as good for my use case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about:

```
(let [[n m] (split-with (partial not= :b) [:a :b :c :b :d])] (concat n (rest m)))
```

Which splits the list at :b and then removes the :b and concats the two lists.

Comment: Beat me to it!  It's really convenient that `split-with` does the Right Thing when the element is not found in the list, so that this solution is easy to write.

Comment: Very elegant. I think it worth noteing that `split-with` is built on top of `take-while` and `drop-while` which are more basic building blocks for tackling similar problems.

Comment: +1 – it's very elegant! It's also worth mentioning that this will not remove all occurrences of `:b` but only the first one (actually I thought the former).
Quick link to doc: http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/split-with

Answer (score 10):

I usually solve these problems with a higher-order function like `split-with`, but someone's already done that. Sometimes it's more readable or more efficient to work at a more primitive level, so here's a better version of your original looping code, using lazy sequences and generalized to take a predicate for removal instead of being constrained to equality checks:

```
(defn remove-once [pred coll]
  ((fn inner [coll]
     (lazy-seq
      (when-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
        (if (pred x)
          xs
          (cons x (inner xs))))))
   coll))


user> (remove-once #{:b} [:a :b :c :b :d])
(:a :c :b :d)
```

Comment: Note I'm not claiming this is more readable, but it is more efficient and it can be good practice if you're familiar with HOFs like `split-with` and need some practice with "good" recursive code.

Comment: Thanks also for a nice example of using lazy-seq! The ["canonical" explanation of laziness](http://clojure.org/lazy) is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It is surprising there is not a high-level API to do something like this. Here is another version similar to @amalloy and @James that uses recur in order not to stack overflow.

```
(defn remove-once [x c]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  (letfn [(rmv [x c1 c2 b]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            (if-let [[v & c] (seq c1)]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
              (if  (and (= x v) b)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                (recur x c c2 false)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                (recur x c (cons v c2) b))                                                                                                                                                                                                  
              c2))]                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    (lazy-seq (reverse (rmv x c '() true)))))                                                                                                                                                                                               

(remove-once :b [:a :b :c :b :d])
;; (:a :c :b :d)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I hate this implementation. You're solving a non-problem - my version doesn't blow the stack either, and I don't waste a bunch of energy calling `reverse` - I build it the right way round to begin with.