# Need a similar function to disj but for a list in clojure. Is it overall possible?

Tags: clojure

I need to traverse a list and do some calculations with every element and the elements excluding that element. For example, having a list `(1 2 3 1)`, I need pairs `(1) (2 3 1)`, `(2) (1 3 1)`, `(3) (1 2 1)` and `(1) (2 3 1)`.

Comment: How should the exclusion work? Exclude only the element at this index, or also every other that is equal to it?

Comment: Can the list have multiple elements?  If so, some of the answers below need to take this into account. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662447/what-is-idiomatic-clojure-to-remove-a-single-instance-from-many-in-a-list

Comment: Should exclude only element at a given index. Updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (...) with every element and the elements excluding that element.

*With every element* sounds like a `map`. *Excluding that element* sounds like a `filter`. Let's start with the latter.

```
user=> (filter #(not= % 1) '(1 2 3))
(2 3)
```

Great. Now let's try to map it over all elements.

```
user=> (let [coll '(1 2 3)] (map (fn [elem] (filter #(not= % elem) coll)) coll))
((2 3) (1 3) (1 2))
```

Creating actual pairs is left as an exercise for the reader. Hint: modify the closure used in `map`.

Keep in mind that the solution suggested above should work fine for short lists but it has a complexity of O(n²). Another issue is the fact that collections with duplicates aren't handled correctly.

Let's take a recursive approach instead. We'll base the recursion on `loop` and `recur`.

```
(defn pairs [coll]
  (loop [ahead coll behind [] answer []]
    (if (empty? ahead)
      answer
      (let [[current & remaining] ahead]
        (recur remaining
               (conj behind current)
               (conj answer [(list current)
                             (concat behind remaining)]))))))
```

A trivial example:

```
user=> (pairs '(1 2 3))
[[(1) (2 3)] [(2) (1 3)] [(3) (1 2)]]
```

A vector with duplicates:

```
user=> (pairs [1 5 6 5])
[[(1) (5 6 5)] [(5) (1 6 5)] [(6) (1 5 5)] [(5) (1 5 6)]]
```

Comment: Since map and filter are both lazy, it's only going to be O(n^2) if you realize all the lists. And that's going to be O(n^2) regardless.

Comment: What if you have a list with duplicates? Then `filter` will remove multiple elements. I would go with @skuro's answer instead.

Comment: @noahz, thanks, good point, I've revised the answer. A kind request to the downvoter: could you please take time to reread the revised answer and share your thoughts?

Comment: actually, my solution was also removing the duplicates. I updated it to provide a duplicate safe version

Comment: This is similar to the approach had in mind to handle duplicates - the only thing I might do differently is pull out the loop/recur into a helper fn and wrap the recursive calls in a lazy-seq to avoid computing the whole thing at once.

Comment: Thanks. I am really a newbie in Clojure so can not decide which solution is "better" - your or skuro's. It would be great if you could somehow compare two.

Comment: @Jan last solution is traversing the collection only once, while mine solution is sacrificing efficiency for readability by iterating with `remove` once per `coll` element. It's ultimately your call and which factor is most important in your code.

Comment: @skuro, thanks for a good summary and a fair comparison of our answers. I find your answer as a good one ‒ have an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

Seems a job for a list comprehension:

```
(defn gimme-pairs [coll]
  (for [x coll]
    [(list x) (remove #{x} coll)]))

user=> (gimme-pairs [1 2 3])
([(1) (2 3)] [(2) (1 3)] [(3) (1 2)])
```

I would actually skip creating a list for the single element, which would make the code even easier:

```
(defn gimme-pairs [coll]
  (for [x coll]
    [x (remove #{x} coll)]))

user=> (gimme-pairs [1 2 3])
([1 (2 3)] [2 (1 3)] [3 (1 2)])
```

If you need to keep duplicates then you can use an indexed collection:

```
(defn gimme-pairs [coll]
  (let [indexed (map-indexed vector coll)
        remove-index (partial map second)]
    (for [[i x] indexed]
      [x (remove-index (remove #{[i x]} indexed))])))

user=> (gimme-pairs [1 2 3 1])
([1 (2 3 1)] [2 (1 3 1)] [3 (1 2 1)] [1 (1 2 3)])
```

Comment: +1 on the idiomatic use of #{x} as a predicate in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

```
(def l [1 2 3])

(first (reduce (fn [[res ll] e]
                 [(conj res [(list e) (rest ll)])
                  (conj (vec (rest ll)) e)])
               [[] l] l))
=> [[(1) (2 3)] [(2) (3 1)] [(3) (1 2)]]
```

Comment: The solution sorts lists and I want to keep the original order.