# Where is this list coming from in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and fairly new to functional programming in general.  I'm trying to create an anagram generator that produces all possible rearrangements of a string.  I thought I'd generalize it and come up with all possible rearrangements of a list.

My attempt:

```
(defn pairs [items]
  (list (list (first items) (last items))
        (list (last items) (first items))))

(defn prepend-to-list-or-item [item coll]
  (if (coll? coll)
    (map #(cons item %) coll)
    (list item coll)))

(defn remove-one [coll item]
  (let [[n m]
        (split-with (partial not= item) coll)]
    (concat n (rest m))))

(defn get-combinations [items]
  (cond (= 0 (count items)) nil
        (= 1 (count items)) items
        (= 2 (count items)) (pairs items)
        :else
        (map #(prepend-to-list-or-item % (get-combinations (remove-one items %))) items)))
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting lists that are nested too deeply.  The output I'm getting is:

```
clojure-test.combinations> (clojure.pprint/pprint (get-combinations '(\a \b \c)))
(((\a \b \c) (\a \c \b))
 ((\b \a \c) (\b \c \a))
 ((\c \a \b) (\c \b \a)))
nil
```

My desired output:

```
((\a \b \c) (\a \c \b) (\b \a \c) (\b \c \a) (\c \a \b) (\c \b \a))
```

With more list items, the problem gets worse.

So, two questions:

1. Where is this extra level of nesting coming from?  I've tried various versions of cons, concat, list, etc. to no avail.
2. What can I do to make this more "Clojury?"

Comment: `What can I do to make this more "Clojury?"` - this is often referred to as 'more idiomatic' - As in "How can I make this clojure code more idiomatic?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
:else
    (mapcat #(
```

in get-combinations

---

Why:

```
(map list-producing-function a-list) ; will give you a list of lists
```

---

ad 2.)

*I rephrased `coll` to `chars` and `item` to `char` - this was for my understanding only*

you can simplify **remove-one**

(if I read it correctly you do want coll without item, which is exactly what `filter` is for)

```
(defn remove-one [chars char]
  (filter (partial not= char) chars))
```

**get-combinations**, more readable case statement

```
(let [char-count (count chars)]
   (case char-count
          0 nil
          1 chars
          2 (pairs chars)
          (mapcat
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  Thanks, man.  I guess I need to play with `map` and friends more.

Comment: Using case does look cleaner.  I can't use `filter` because I need to preserve duplicates.  I grabbed the `split-with` solution from [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662447/what-is-idiomatic-clojure-to-remove-a-single-instance-from-many-in-a-list)