# how to dropFirst takeFirst item according to a predicate in scala

Tags: scala

I have these elements shuffled in a list

`val list = (1,2,3,0, 0)`

I need to split this list into two lists.

```
val list1 = (1)
val list2 = (2, 3, 0, 0)
```

The first list contains a single item that is not a `0`, the second list contains the rest of the items.

Fix below code, so  `list1 never contains 0` and `list1 :: list2 == list`

```
val list = (1, 2, 0, 3, 0).shuffle

val list1 = list(0)
val list2 = list drop 1
```

Somewhat similar to this: [How should I remove the first occurrence of an object from a list in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716455/how-should-i-remove-the-first-occurrence-of-an-object-from-a-list-in-scala)

Comment: If the list is shuffled, I'm not sure the second requirement could hold. Assume the order is (0,1,2,3,0), the first list should contain (1), but concatenating them would give us (1,0,2,3,0). Can the second requirement be relaxed such that `list1::list2` has the same members and count as `list`, but not the same order?

Comment: order doesn't matter @MichaelBar-Sinai

Comment: What solutions have you already tried?

Comment: @MichaelBar-Sinai, I think when the first element is 0, `list1` must be empty to preserve the invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start from the following function:

```
def sep(l: List[Int]) = 
  (l.find(_ != 0).toList, 
   l.takeWhile(_ == 0) ::: l.dropWhile(_ == 0).tail)
```

It returns what you need if solution exists:

```
sep(List(0, 1, 0, 2, 3)) -> (List(1),List(0, 0, 2, 3))
sep(List(1, 4, 0, 2, 3)) -> (List(1),List(4, 0, 2, 3))
sep(List(0, 0, 4, 5))    -> (List(4),List(0, 0, 5))
```

But if you have `List(0,0)`... The next step is to write it recursively so it uses the only one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways of doing this, here's mine:

```
val list = List(0,1,0,3,2)
val list1 = List(list.find(_!=0).get)
val list2 = list.filter( _!=list1(0) )
```

End results (Scala REPL)

```
list: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 0, 3, 2)
list1: List[Int] = List(1)
list2: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 3, 2)
```

Note that this code assumes `list` has at list one non-zero member.

Updated (per @theArchetypalPaul's remark) to support lists with non-unique non-zero members:

```
val temp = list.span( _ == 0 )
val list1 = List(temp._2.head)
val list2 = temp._1 ++ temp._2.tail
```

Comment: Fails for `0,1,0,1,0` (or any list where the non-zero element returned by the `find` is repeated again in the list)

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer. Based on the question, I assumed all non-zero members of the input list are unique.

Comment: Fails if they're all zero :)

Comment: Now you're trollin' :-) I clearly stated that. It probably also fails for an empty list. The point was to suggest a way of achieving the request clearly, not come up with production-grade code. That would also include unit tests, and probably changing `list1` to `Option[Int]`.