# scala "remove" not working

Tags: scala

According to page 44 of the book "Programming in Scala", there exists a `remove` function for the `list` data structure. However, when I try the example in my interpreter, I keep getting errors. Does anyone know why? Here is a sample

```
scala> val x = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> x.remove(_ < 5)
<console>:9: error: value remove is not a member of List[Int]
              x.remove(_ < 5)
                ^

scala> x.remove(s => s == 5)
<console>:9: error: value remove is not a member of List[Int]
              x.remove(s => s == 5)
                ^

scala> val y = List("apple","Oranges","pine","sol")
y: List[String] = List(apple, Oranges, pine, sol)

scala> y.remove(s => s.length ==4)
<console>:9: error: value remove is not a member of List[String]
              y.remove(s => s.length ==4)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`List` had a remove method in earlier versions, but it has been deprecated in 2.8 and removed in 2.9. Use `filterNot` instead.

Comment: Can you be more specific? In the deprecation filterNot has been named as replacement and a test yielded the same result for me.

Comment: My mistake.  I was misremebering `-`.

Answer (score 4):

[ListBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer) has a remove method, but not [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). See [here for info on how to idiomatically remove from an immutable List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636717/what-is-an-idiomatic-scala-way-to-remove-one-element-from-an-immutable-list) (obviously creating a new List!)