# Breaking out of a for loop scala?

Tags: scala

I need to get out of a for loop in scala, but when I try to change the value of `i` past its limit my IDE says that `i` is a `val` so I can't change it. How do I get around this?

Also, if `i` is a `val` can I not use it as an index of lists because it will always be the same value?

I'm trying to go though a list and if the list contains a key (which is a string), I remove it from the list. However if it has multiple instances of this string I only want to remove one, so I want to get out of the for loop after I find the first instance of the key.

```
 for (i <- 0 to d.length-1){
   if (key == d(i)){
     d=d.patch(i,Nil,1)
     i=d.length

   }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Explaining a little more about what this code should be doing would help refactor it.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636717/what-is-an-idiomatic-scala-way-to-remove-one-element-from-an-immutable-list

Answer (score 1):

In scala, a variable declared as `val` is immutable -- it can never be changed.  In each iteration of your `for` loop, the index variable `i` is similarly immutable.  Idiomatic scala relies heavily on this  paradigm of immutability.  Collections are usually also declared as `val`, and then reassigned to a new variable when a `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, or other operation is performed.

For your example, you might do something like this:

```
val data = Seq("foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "baz", "qux")
val newData = data diff Seq("bar")
```

Or:

```
val (first, second) = data.splitAt(data.indexOf("bar"))
val newData = first ++ second.tail
```

Now `newData` will lose 1 instance of  "bar".  There are many other ways to do this, many of which are documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636717/what-is-an-idiomatic-scala-way-to-remove-one-element-from-an-immutable-list) similar question.